# How to replace a character in a pattern in unix

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

I have to search for a string in a particular position and if the string contains `{`, then it has to be replaced with `0`.

For example:

```
text='i have 45320{ dollar'
```

In above example, `{` needs to be replaced with `0` and at the same corresponding number needs to be converted with 2 decimal places.

Expected output:

```
text='i have 4532.00 dollar'
```

Is it possible to implement this logic in unix using sed?

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`, you can do:

```
$ text='i have 45320{ dollar'
$ sed 's/\(.\){/.\10/' <<< "$text"
i have 4532.00 dollar
```

Comment: Thanks!! It is worked. Can you please check this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790322/how-to-convert-the-string-to-negative-decimal-number-in-ksh-unix/36790799#36790799