# How to convert the string to negative decimal number in ksh - unix

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

if a particular character is found at certain position, I need to replace it with a number and make entire string as negative decimal number  .
for ex:

if `}` is found at 14th position it need to be replaced with 2 and make it negative decimal number:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{9\}\)}/.\12/;s/\(.\)/-\1/' <<< '123 00}000150}'
```

output is:

```
-.123 00}0001502
```

But, expected output is:

```
123 -00}00015.02
```

Comment: How come `123` in output but not seen anywhere in input?

Comment: Sorry i will edit that part!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
sed -e 's/\(.* \)\(.\{8\}\)\(.*\)}/\1-\2.\32/' <<< '123 00}000150}'
```

`\1` will have value: `123` ( Matches from first character till first space)

`\2` : `00}00015` ( Next 8 characters)

`\3` : `0` ( Characters until next `}` is found)

Comment: Thanks. It is worked !! can you tell me what is .\32 ?

Comment: Edited the answer.  `2` is just digit added at the end. `\3` we get from input.